# Creating custom order by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

Customer wants to display a list of values returned by my query in a specific order.  The issue is ordering simply by asc or desc is not giving me what the customer want.  DBA doesn't want me to hard code values.  Is there a way to custom sort without hard coding values?  Because the values will change every year and would have to maintain/update it every year.

```
Table Structure:
Column:  CMN_CodesID (unique), Name (is what I'd like to display in custom order)
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom order? Are you saying you want to set the order by dynamically?

Comment: Yes.  I want to display results in specific order.  Example:  Jack, Apple, Orange, Mango, Banana.   I want to make sure that my result always shows Jack, Apple and Orange first in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this.

```
order by case when Jack then 1 
          when Apple then 2 
          when Orange then 3 
          ...
         End
```

Comment: There is no other way besides hard coding values in order by?

Comment: @NonProgrammer - As far as i know this is the only way in sql server

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic sql in a stored procedure and pass `@MyOrderBy` into it as a parameter (Added to this example for illustration).

```
DECLARE @MyOrderBy VARCHAR(300)
SELECT @MyOrderBy = 'case when myfield = ''Jack'' then 1  when myfield = ''Apple'' then 2  when myfield = ''Orange'' then 3 else 4 End'


DECLARE @sSQL VARCHAR(300)

SELECT @sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY ' + @MyOrderBy


EXEC(@sSQL)
```

Comment: @Sean-Lange I think its all to easy to shout SQL Injection without thinking about the situation fully. Yes this would be open to SQL Injection IF the value in '@MyOrderBy' was user input. In this case it's not so not vulnerable.

Comment: your recommendation is to use a stored procedure which receives a string as input. That means the procedure IS vulnerable to injection. Just because the usage today is not user input does not mean it can't be at some point. A cross reference table would be a better approach. This could be a persistent table or even a table valued parameter that has the sort order for the values. Why keep something vulnerable when there are other solutions that aren't?

Comment: Additionally, the reason here is because the DBA (rightfully) doesn't want a hardcoded list for the sort order. I suspect that such a DBA would never allow something with an order by parameter and executing it in dynamic sql.